# Stripe - Invoice Item included on recurring payment and charge failed

Tags: stripe-payments, credit-card, subscription, invoice

I have a recurring subscription service using Stripe. An additional Invoice Item is added to each invoice.

When a new user wants to subscribe to my service, the steps are:

1. create user (*if not already existing*)
2. create invoice item (*will be added to the next invoice*)
3. create subscription for the user (*creates an invoice*)

The problem is when the card is valid but can't be charged: the invoice isn't created, and the item stays in pending state, waiting for the next invoice.

Each time the customer retries, there is one more pending item, and if it finally works, he has to pay for the normal price and all the pending items.

What's the best way to handle this kind of thing?